# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, message

I have a search feature (written by my predecessor) which takes date range, id, available programs as input and displays the results in a gridview. The feature works fine most of the time (I have tested it) but for one of the users of my application it gave this error message. I am not able to reproduce this error by myself in order to fix it. Don't know what's wrong!

Can you guys help?

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
>   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
>   at APP_ViewFollowupWorkload.GetFilterString() in d:\SharedServices\APP\ViewFollowupWorkload.aspx.cs:line 1415
>   at APP_ViewFollowupWorkload.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\SharedServices\APP\ViewFollowupWorkload.aspx.cs:line 268
>   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>    at ASP.app_viewfollowupworkload_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bad754dd\a11f74ff\App_Web_viewfollowupworkload.aspx.ae7ca9bd.uwyek3vs.0.cs:line 0
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Here is the .cs file code where the error generating:

```
if (txtDateTo.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            if (txtDateTo.ToString().Length > 2)
                strFilter = strFilter + " AND submission_date <= ''" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTo.ToString()) + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)) + "''";

    }
```

Comment: Try to log the date, and let the user do his magic. Alternative, surround it with a try/catch and mail the stack tace + the user input to your mail. Then you get notified next time the error happens and you get the buggy date.

Answer (score 5):

The error indicates that the passes in value of `txtDateTo` is not a valid `DateTime` - say `32/11/2011`.

You can change the code to something that will not throw an exception by using one of the [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) overloads. This will not parse invalid values, but will avoid an exception being thrown - you still need to determine what to do in such a case.

Comment: Agreed but since this is a user-entered value I would suggest using a `CompareValidator` with `CompareValidator.Operator = "DataTypeCheck"` and `CompareValidator.Type = "Date"` to prevent the user from entering an invalid date string to begin with.  Don't forget to implement server-side validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ParseExact instead - here ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx))
.

Maybe they use some unusual date time format. Ask your user which value in textbox is used to convert to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` as below

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("25/12/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

or

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("25/12/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> The third parameter IFormatProvider specifies the culture. If the
> string comes from the user, you should pass
> CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, otherwise, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.
> CultureInfo.CurrentCulture will use the settings from Regional Options
> in Control Panel specified by the user.